# How can I use git behind a firewall

Tags: git

I am being a company firewall, and I am trying to retrieve Webkit source by doing 'git clone git://git.webkit.org/WebKit.git WebKit'. But my company is blocking 'git' protocol. Is there anyway to work around this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not just have the company firewall changed so as to allow you to do your job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here: http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/UsingGitWithWebKit

You have to use `git-svn` anyway and that is based on the SVN repo exposed through http, which should be allowed in your company.

The git repo doesn't have all branches and you can't push to it ( though I don't think you were planning on doing that.)

Answer (score 0):

As workaround use subversion to get sources of the WebKit :) (from http://www.webkit.org/building/checkout.html):

```
svn checkout http://svn.webkit.org/repository/webkit/trunk WebKit
```

If you want only git, check if repository is available via https, if not may be your company provides http proxy and you can use git port via proxy (use git config --global http.proxy http://proxy:8080 to setup).